# Syntax error on open() in Python 3, don't know why

Tags: python, python-3.x

SOLVED

I am working out of the "Learn Python the Hard Way" book, and I keep getting a syntax error when trying to open this file, I may just be doing something stupid, and missing something obvious, but I can't figure it out. Any help much appreciated.

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print(f.read())

def rewind(f):
    print(f.seek(0))

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print(line_count, f.readline()

current_file = open("input_file")

print("First let's print the whole file: \n")

print_all(current_file)

print("Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape")

rewind(current_file)

print("Finally, let's print three lines:")

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

The error is being thrown where I try and declare the variable current_file and assign it to open("input_file") Again thank you.

Comment: Count the open and close parentheses on the line reading `print(line_count, f.readline()`.

Comment: Please show the full traceback as well as the contents of the files. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I feel so very stupid.

Comment: FWIW, you should use context managers. `with open(...) as f:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line above is missing a `)`.

```
print(line_count, f.readline()
```

Comment: Thank you I figured it out.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp C'mon man. I know I answered my fair share of "typo questions" when starting out, but these types of questions should really be closed and deleted. Not answered. But, in the end, the choice is yours.

Comment: @leaf: I don't really feel like taking such a hard line.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yikes! Sorry if I came across wrong. And, as I said before, it is only a suggestion.

Comment: @leaf: No, you came across fine.  The issue is complex, and there are a lot of ideas about how to keep the site clean but still accessible to newbies.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Mabye we should have a new site called _newbies overflow_ :P Anyway, I'll leave you alone, and give it rest.

Answer (score 0):

You missed one ')' in this line.

print(line_count, f.readline()

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parentheses character ')' in `print(line_count, f.readline()`.

Please replace the line with:
    print(line_count, f.readline())

Answer (score 0):

You have missed one parentheses in a print statement. Please correct it as following and then try,

```
def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print(line_count, f.readline())
```